# webscraping with pop up login window

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to webscraping information from an url, the login is a pop up window, I used below code but it does not work.

```
import requests

data = {
    'username': 'email',
    'hash': 'password',
    'form_id': 'login_form',
    'op': 'login <button class="btn btn-lg btn-blue" type="submit"></button>',
}
url = 'https://www.canstar.com.au/'
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

result of print(r.text) is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I print out the login form, screenshot is below:
[image]

what's the right way to scrape info when login is a popup window like this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for your problem is, use the `Selenium` library to close any pop-up or log in with a username and password.
with a line of code like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('Xpath address').click()
```